# fake currency detection in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a project on fake currency detection. I am a beginner at matlab could not solve some errors.

code:

```
 global img;
img=imread('image.jpg');
B=im2bw(img);
figure,
imshow(img);
imgd = im2double(img);
I=imresize(imgd,0.9);
figure,imshow(I);
imgt = (0.3 * (I(:,:,1)) + 0.59 * (I(:,:,2)) + 0.11 * (I(:,:,3)))/255;
figure,imshow(imgt);
s=edge(imgt,'sobel',0.09);
figure,
imshow(s);
```

the problem is that when i apply the threshold the image doesnot show an threshold rather whole the image is made black.

Comment: Your problem is caused by the division factor `255` in `imgt`. You've already normalised the image in the 0-1 range by using `im2double` in line 6.  Removing `/255` from `imgt` (line 9) will fix your issue. Alternate fix is to use `imshow(imgt,[]);` but there is no need to introduce the problem in the first place. Other than that, avoid using global variables

Comment: yeah thanks its fixed